# pgfplots units breaks when using classicthesis

Tags: pgfplots, siunitx, classicthesis

I have some math-expression I want to have as a unit in a PGF plot. However, the greek letter is replaced by a horizontal line, if I activate the `classicthesis` package.

Here a MWE (it works if I comment out the `\usepackage{classicthesis}`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}



\begin{document}

$\mu_\text{B}$

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y unit =\mu_\text{B}]
    \addplot [very thick, blue,domain={-pi:pi}] {x^2};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture} %

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pgfplots seems to typeset the unit with `\mathrm`. This is imho not a good idea and should be reported as a bug. It breaks if mathpazo is loaded by classicthesis. You can get around the problem by inserting a \mbox or use \si{\micro}:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}


$\alpha\mu_\text{B}$

$\mathrm{\alpha\mu_\text{B}}$ %wrong

$\mathrm{\mbox{$\alpha\mu$}}$

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[y unit =\mbox{$\mu_\text{B}$}]
    \addplot [very thick, blue,domain={-pi:pi}] {x^2};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture} %

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[y unit =\si{\micro}_\text{B}]
    \addplot [very thick, blue,domain={-pi:pi}] {x^2};
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture} %

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the `\mbox` because I think for custom fonts the `\micro` is not necessarily identical to the `\mu`.